# DNS and URL Mapping

Tags: domain-name-system, rewrite

I have content which is hosted on serverA.com/site, however, when a user visits serverB.com/sitename, I would like it to load the content of serverA.com/site (while the url is sitll on serverB).

Is this possilbe, and if so, how?

Comment: Telling at least which web server software you're using would be helpful...

Comment: Both servers are running apache

Answer (score 3):

AFAICS you need to reverse-proxy connections for that.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /sitename/ http://serverA.com/site/
ProxyPassReverse /sitename/ http://serverA.com/site/
```

See [here](http://thelowedown.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/reverse-proxy-with-apache/) for a more detailed explanation, and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) for the mod_proxy documentation.